# jquery change div height temporary / until user clicks anywhere else

Tags: jquery, css, temporary

I have a #content div with a default css height: auto. After clicking on a button and submitting a form, I change the height of my content-div to 300:

```
if(msg == 'OK')
{
    result = '<div class="notification_ok">Thank you.</div>';    
    $("#content").height(300);
}
```

But it should only have that height while the user is on that specific page and when he clicks on any another link, the height should be set to 'auto' again. I thought about adding css classes

```
.heightAuto { height: auto; }
.height300 { height: 300; }
```

and just say

```
$("#content").toggleClass(heightAuto height300);
```

but then I think I have to add a class="heightAuto" to every link because I'm loading my links dynamically into my content-div in order to not having to reload the page every time. Isn't there any better way with jquery or setting the css style temporary?

Comment: does your link's take you to a new page on same window ? if so you don't need to do anything

Comment: Since you're loading the content dynamically, can you just `$("#content").height("auto");` in the function that places the new content in the `div`?

Comment: Did my answer help you out at all?

Answer (score 0):

What is your target audience for this project? If it is all modern browsers (IE9+), you could always use the CSS pseudo selector `:not()`:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp

```
:not(.height300){
    height:auto;
}
```

Then you wouldn't have to explicitly set the `.heightAuto` class in your server scripting.